# Choosing between "A" or "The"

Tags: articles

I recently posted a picture on my facebook showing an image of a wallet with a married couple photograph in it. The image itself already had a funny caption. I added my own caption for the picture just like the following :

"The important function of putting wife's photographs in the wallets"

Before the words "important", should I use "an" or "the",
Before the words "wallets", should I use "the" or no articles?

Comment: Your sentence is a bit confusing. Are you talking only about the one man's wife whose photograph is in the wallet under consideration or all all wives in general? Are there one or many photographs of the wife? In general, the sentence would go "the important function of putting/having (the/one's) wife's photograph in wallets."

Comment: What was the funny caption, please? Was your comment meant to be ironic, or cheerful? I would have said "[*The importance of placing ... *](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22The+importance+of+placing%22&tbm=bks)"

Comment: related: **1**. [Usage of English definite article when referring to generic word](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93834/usage-of-english-definite-article-when-referring-to-generic-word) **2.** [The use of the definite article “The”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/217858/the-use-of-the-definite-article-the) **3** [Are there any simple rules for choosing the definite vs. indefinite (vs. none) article?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-choosing-the-definite-vs-indefinite-vs-none-a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the word "The" you are pointing to a known singular noun.  E.g. "The Statue of Liberty" means you are talking about the authentic original statue that exists in the New York harbor.  If you use the article "A" before this statement then you are referring any given noun or object.  E.g "A Statue of Liberty" meaning some statue of liberty but not a specific one.  So if you are to be using the word "The" you should make sure that the reader knows what object (or noun) you are speaking of, otherwise it becomes a question in the readers mind.  Here's an example of how you might use 'The' in a paragraph where you have established the noun and the reader will know what you are speaking of.

I came across a man who wore a red hat and had a weird smile on his face.  The man came to me and asked for some money because he was poor.

Notice before I use 'The' in front of the word man, I establish who I am talking about.

If the noun is well known or has a title that is known that is a singular object then I can use 'The' without having to justify who I'm speaking of.

The Pope came to the door.

There is only one Pope and so I don't have to signify exactly which Pope.

Hope this makes sense.